# Altium repeated harness connector

Tags: altium, bus

I would like to use a harness connector to connect two sheets in a multichannel design. If I do not repeat the sheets, the harness connector between them works well. It's better if I show it in pictures:
[image: Not repeated sheets]
Clearly can see that I can connect the two resistors on the PCB.

But if I would like to repeat connected sheets together with the harness connector using REPEAT command, I cannot assign the right net on the PCB to the resistors:
[image: Repeated harness]

I get an error:

`Net with name "harness_conn.SigA_N" already exist`

I tried many options, in a different ways, but until now I cannot manage to work repeated harnesses through repeated sheets. Can anyone have a solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/610586/2028

Comment: It's just showing an alternative method, its not really answering the question how to repeat signal harness.

Comment: You might need to contact Altium on this one. I did that for a similar issue I had regarding repeated sheets and differential nets. The answer was basically that it was not supported, so [my workaround](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/582014/2028) felt kludgy.

Comment: It may or may not apply to your situation, but here is a direct quote from my Altium support case: "...You cannot connect harnesses through busses but you can connect harnesses through other harnesses. Harness connectors are incompatible with the automatic repeat functionality of the MultiChannel design tools. A solution would be to break your harnesses out into individual wires."